# Ternary operator and Func, Action, Predicate

Tags: c#, .net

I am wondering why I cannot use ternary operator with Func, Action and Predicate.

Here is a simple example that does not compile:

```
bool condition = true;
Action show = condition ? () => Console.Write("true") : () => Console.Write("false");
```

It says:

> There is no implicit conversion between 'lambda expression' and
>   'lambda expression'

Also I cannot do an explicit cast:

```
Action show = (Action)(true ? () => Console.Write("true") : () => Console.Write("false"));
```

Comment: try casting the lambdas to action?
Like this

(Action)(() => Console.Write("Bleh"))

Comment: (I think I've found reasonable duplicate, please comment if that duplicate is not enough... Make sure to search for something like "C# lambda ternary implicit conversion" to see if there is better duplicate as this question is asked a lot).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov technically my question is wider. Practically they are similar.

Comment: Try with this code
Action show = condition ? new Action(()=> Console.Write("true")) : new Action(() => Console.Write("false"));